# Dismiss handling of Android DialogFragment with fullscreen on smaller devices and dialog on large devices

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, dismiss, dialogfragment

I have implemented custom DialogFragment to get some inputs from user.

```
 if(mIsLargeLayout) {
            // The device is using a large layout, so show the fragment as a dialog
            userDeviceDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, USER_DEVICE_DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        } else {
            // The device is smaller, so show the fragment fullscreen
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            // Transition animation
            fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            // To make it fullscreen, use the 'content' root view as the container
            // for the fragment, which is always the root view for the activity
            fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, userDeviceDialogFragment)
                               .addToBackStack(null)
                               .commit();
        }
```

I have now such problem.

1. When there is large screen then DialogFragment uses Dialog and I can override **onDismiss** method and be notified that Dialog is closing.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
       super.onDismiss(dialog);

       Log.d(TAG, "onDismiss method called.");

       if(mOnDialogEventListener != null) {
           mOnDialogEventListener.onDialogClose();
       }
   }
   ```

   Then I can notify Activity about Dialog (DialogFragment) close.
2. If screen is smaller I display **DialogFragment** as **Fragmen**t in full screen mode with **Toolbar**. This **DialogFragment** can be dismissed by **X button, Add button and Back Button**. But **onDismiss()** overridden method is not called anymore. How can I notify my parent **Activity** about DialogFragment being dismissed regardless it was back button or action button on toolbar. 
   I consider directly calling Callback (Delegate method) `mOnDialogEventListener.onDialogClose();`

But how can I handle Back Button? OK I could override it inside Activity but now how to limit it to situation when there was DialogFragment displayed.

**REASON:** 
I think I need this Dialog close notification in my Activity to redraw RecyclerView list. It seems that when DialogFragment is in the foreground, then while rotating device RecyclerView is redrawing incorrectly (icons and text is messed up). So I think I should stop redrawing of RecyclerView when DialogFragment is displayed and then redraw it  after DialogFragment will be closed.

[image]]
[image]

I don't know why this layout is messing up, but it happens after displaying DialogFragment (fullscreen) + rotating device. I think CursorLoader is refreshing and redrawing in background could not calculate correct sizes i.e. 2/10 and 8/10 weights of horizontal LinearLayout of each item in RecyclerView?

**TO SUM UP:**

1. How to get notified about model and fullscreen DialogFragment being closed to enable RecyclerView refresh?
2. Is there other solution to handle this issue to correctly redraw RecyclerView on orientation change while DialogFragment is displayed?

Comment: I think that a full-screen `DialogFragment` is possible. Is there some reason you wouldn't just do the full-screen `DialogFragment` when needed?

Comment: It's rather problem with RecyclerView after dismissing DialogFragment, results of RecyclerView are messed up, images and textviews are incorrectly layouted. I would like to catch all situations when DialogFragment is dismissed in order to tigger some RecyclerView refeshing code. But Now, I have shifted 2 HashMap and 2 ArrayList datasets of RecyclerView to SortedList with wrapper items around current datasets items . Now it seems to work correctly without the need to do any additional fixing after DialogFragment is dismissed.